# JavaScript nested loops make function execute too slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a function that includes some nested for loops and works as intended.

**The issue** however, is that it has to loop through a lot of data, meaning that **it takes too long** to execute and often freezes the browser while it executes.

Data got from server is in the order of 2000+ elements.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way of writing this function that will reduce the number of iterations and speed up the process?

```js
function markers(boxes) {
    $.getJSON('empdata.json', function (data) {

          var json = data;
          for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {

              for(var v = 0; v < json.length; v++) {

                  //loop through parsed markers within bounds
                  var obj = json[v];
                  if (boxes[i].contains(new google.maps.LatLng(obj.latitude, obj.longitude))) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj.latitude, obj.longitude),
                        map: map,
                    });

                  } else {
                      console.log("out of box");
                  }
              } //close bounds markers 

          } //close full loop parse
    })
};
```

The first part of the function simply gets data about map locations from a static JSON file using the jQuery `$.GetJSON` function.

The second part loops through boundary boxes that have been created depending on the parameters given. Finally the third part loops through each item in the JSON file and creates a map pin if it is inside the given boundaries.

I think the problem is that there can many boxes to loop through and this multiplied by the 2000+ items in the JSON file means that function has to go through thousands of iterations each time.

Comment: If the objective of question is to get optimization/ improvements and your existing code works fine, you should put question on [CodeReviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Also for code freezing browser, you can look into web workers, service workers

Comment: There are data structures that can help, but it's kind-of a big topic. One way would be to group your "boxes" into quadrants, and sub-quadrants, and sub-sub-quadrants etc, so that you drastically reduce the number of object-to-box comparisons.

Comment: Despite the fact the comments before this one are good and should be taken into consideration in my opinion a very important point here is also taking away the calculation load from the browser i.e. using an async call to let the iterations be done by the backend and therefore making sure to not overload the frontend. You can then use the data calculated with a provided callback function and won't have any browser freezes. (This, of course, will not increase calculation / iteration speed but IMHO is still an important thing to think of in this situation).

Answer (score 2):

The bottleneck in your code is not the nested loops itself, but rather it's the google marker print that is very very slow.

However you can do some things like:

- avoid the REcreation of temporary variables like `var obj = json[v];` because it creates a lot of overhead. It is better to reassign that variable. (This principle is also at the base of fast js gaming libraries like Phaser.io. Same situation for:

  - `for (var i = 0 ...`
  - `for(var v = 0 ...`
  - `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ ...`
- avoid recall of `new google.maps.LatLng(obj.latitude, obj.longitude)` the creation of new objects is more expensive than assignation.
- you can replace the creation of markers with [fusion tables](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#fusiontables)
- make markers as thinner as possible
- Use [DOM DocumentFragments](http://nickjohnson.com/b/google-maps-v3-how-to-quickly-add-many-markers) (if you see [here](http://nickjohnson.com/c/map/slow.php?v=3.3) the print is almost instantaneous)
- do not console log because it is REALLY slow! Better attach text to DOM div acting as on-page log.
- go async! try delegate the print of a single marker to an async callback in order to avoid the time spent waiting the end of the marker creation.
- what is the complexity of `boxes[i].contains()`? Look that it is in the inner loop, so it is run N * M times, where N is the length of `boxes` and M the length of `json`. In computation theory, the more is optimized this function, the faster the whole snipped runs.

---

**EDIT:**

Found an interesting [quick script](http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/dd3d288b0290a0cbb0f6) that benchmarks sync 2K marker generation vs async one. On my pc elapsed time dropped of about 22 times when going async.

The core function is:

```
var createmarker=function(coordinates,index) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var neighborMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coordinates,
      map: map,
      title:'Marker '+index,
      icon: 'https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/238439/4837489/46de6daa-5fd7-11e4-9622-0e1cc674f6b2.png'
    });

    markersArray.push(neighborMarker );
  },10);
};

clearMarkers('Asynchronous',function(coordsArray,timeini) {
  for(var index=0;index<coordsArray.length;index++) {
    createmarker(coordsArray[index], index);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hi  im not sure if this will be of any help but how im understanding it  your function has to go trough a big data base and because of that its slow.

so would it be a good solution to  divide your database  so add a general parameter that can divide your gigantic database into 4-8 smaller ones and make sure or that it will go trough them one by one or just immediately to the one it has to go to

like i said  dunno if its gonna be of any help

Comment: So if I understand right, you want OP to load partial data. Smaller chunks and append it, more like feeds on FB. Am I right?

Comment: yea so the browser wont choke on a big piece of data

Comment: Instead of cut the database the OP can simply query on indexes. O(2K) is nothing than huge data.

Comment: I would still recommend web workers as even this chunk, if big enough, will cause freeze